# rpmUtils.miscutils in python3.6

Tags: python-3.6, rpm, rhel

I am refactoring code from python2(RHEL 7.6) to python3(RHEL 8.2) and I have problem with missing library in python3.6.

Problem:

`from rpmUtils.miscutils import splitFilename ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rpmUtils'`

I've tried to install python3-dnf and python3-rpm packages to RHEL8, but still not working. Is there any solution how to use this library in python3.6 and RHEL8 or should I write some custom function by myself?

Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This library was indeed removed, but you have several other options you can use.

Please note that these other functions expect to receive a string in the NEVRA (name, epoch, version, release, architecture) format as an input, not a filename. Thus you must remove the '.rpm' extension of the filename, in order to get a NVRA string (epoch normally is not included in the filename of the RPM package).

So basically you have 2 options:

- to use dnf as suggested in i.e. https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1364504
- to use hawkey i.e. :

  ```
    import hawkey

    rpm_base_filename = os.path.basename(rpm_file)
    nevra = hawkey.split_nevra(rpm_base_filename[:-len(".rpm")])
    name = nevra.name
    version = nevra.version
    release = str(nevra.release)
    epoch = str(nevra.epoch)
    arch = nevra.arch
  ```

For example here is a patch for such modification that I made for one of the tools we use as part of the oVirt release process:

https://github.com/oVirt/releng-tools/commit/823405e6b261f7ff27ddbba0e8fa2b86dd2a8698